# Reading vault secrets from consul-template

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault, consul-template

How do I query just the value of a secret key from consul template ? From vault cli I would do

```
vault read -field=value secret/somekey
```

and it works fine. However, in the consul-template

```
{{secret "secret/somekey"}}
```

returns something like

```
{ 2592000 false map[value:11122222001040]
```

I can see it's outputting lease_duration etc along with the value. How do I get just the value in consul-template ?

Comment: There is an answer. If it is correct, please mark it.

Answer (score 2):

In your template you will need to use:

```
{{with secret "secret/somekey"}}{{.Data.value}}{{end}}
```

In your config file you will also need a section for vault:

```
vault {
  address = "https://vault.service.consul:8200"
  token = "abcd1234"
}
```

or you could use the `VAULT_TOKEN` environment variable.

Comment: how would you iterate over several values not just 1?

Comment: I have a template as below to renew the token and update the tls.key when the `key` is updated in vault

vault {
  renew_token = true
  address = "https://vault.xxx.com/"
}
template {
  destination = "/tmp/tls.key"
  contents = "{{ with secret \"secret/user\" }}{{ .Data.key }}{{ end }}"
}

with consul-template running in the ec2 instance, but the tls.key doesnt get the new vaule when the vault `key` is updated, instead when I reload the consult-template it does updated - but is it possible to get it updated without doing a restart of service?